# Shabbos shacharis - Shabbos and the nations

Tags: tefilla, shabbat, prayer-book, shacharis-morning-prayer

> וְלֹא נְתַתּוֹ ה' אֱלֹהֵֽינוּ לְגוֹיֵי הָאֲרָצוֹת
> וְלֹא הִנְחַלְתּוֹ מַלְכֵּֽנוּ לְעוֹבְדֵי פְסִילִים
> וְגַם בִּמְנוּחָתוֹ לֹא יִשְׁכְּנוּ עֲרֵלִים
> כִּי לְיִשְׂרָאֵל עַמְּךָ נְתַתּוֹ בְּאַהֲבָה, לְזֶֽרַע יַעֲקֹב אֲשֶׁר בָּם
> בָּחָֽרְתָּ.
> Hashem our G-d, you did not give it [Shabbos] to the nations of [other] lands,
> Our king, you did not bequeath it to those who serve carved gods,
> And in its rest the uncircumcized may not dwell,
> Rather, you gave it with love to Israel, your nation,
> to the seed of Yaakov, them whom you chose...

([Shacharis for Shabbos](https://www.sefaria.org/Siddur_Ashkenaz%2C_Shabbat%2C_Shacharit%2C_Amidah%2C_Sanctity_of_the_Day.3?lang=he&with=Translations&lang2=he)) - I think the Sefardi version is also pretty similar.

The author seems to have given three reasons why the nations do not have Shabbos. Aside from the different reasons, phrased as descriptions of the nations (גויי הארצות, עובדי פסילים, ערלים), each has a different verb (נתתו, הנחלתו, ישכנו) and a different reference to Hashem (ה' אלקינו, מלכינו, no reference at all).
Then the prayer continues with a statement about Israel, which I'd like to assume explains why those three reasons don't apply to them.
Has anyone seen a clear explanation of all this?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Shenei_Luchot_HaBerit%2C_Torah_Shebikhtav%2C_Vayakhel%2C_Pekudei%2C_Torah_Ohr.53

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Notes_by_Rabbi_Yehoshua_Hartman_on_Gevurot_Hashem.47.390

Comment: @shmosel Wow! Thank you.

Comment: @shmosel, what am I looking at in the Rav Hartman piece? Where is it holding in Gevuras Hashem and what is it referring to? לצד ימין, לצד שמאל, it all sounds very interesting...

Comment: I also see that in the sefer Tefillah L'Moshe on the davening it quotes R"Y ben Yakar at length, in a peirush that sounds similar to the one here from the Shelah. I don't know how to find that reference online. - I do note that he mentions three quite different girsaos in the second half of the section, the part about Yisrael. I saw that already in that Maharal. So maybe don't be so medayak in that section.

Comment: I _guess_ R"Y ben Yakar is the rebbi of Ramban, author of Maayan Ganim on tefillah, not the rebbi of Rashi.

Comment: That peirush does mention two possibilities: 1) the prayer wanted to include the three verbs (נתתו, הנחלתו, ישכנו), but it doesn't matter which phrase they each went on, or 2) he gives a way to explain why each one is on its respective phrase.